# What does python automatically graph as the y axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've run into a problem with graphing histograms using matplotlib.

I don't actually have a y-axis set, but when I graph agesc it works just fine. It counts the number of values I for a given point of agesc and that's exactly what I want. But I want to normalize the y axis to read from 0 to 1, where the abundance of agesc is simply a value between 0 and 1.

Here's my code:

```
ind = np.where((r >= 3) & (r < 15) & (z >=  2) & (z <= 3) & (ofe > 0.4))
rsc = r[ind]
zsc = z[ind]
fehsc = feh[ind]
agesc = age[ind]

plt.hist(agesc, bins=14/.2)
plt.title('O/Fe')
plt.show()
numsc = number[ind]
```

My questions are this: What does python do to automatically graph the y axis without me defining one?

and second, how can I go about making a second variable, N, that will allow me to graph between 0 and 1 as opposed to 0 and 120 as I am automatically getting right now?

Because whenever I assign some empty array, I get that there are too many values assigned to bin and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What do you mean a "y axis set"? Because you are using `plt.hist` which knows what to do with a single array of data. `matplotlib` is a high-level graphing utility. Use `plt.hist(agesc, bins=14/.2, normed=True)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I mean that in the histogram itself, there is an x axis (the age, in this case) and a y axis (the counts). The range of the counts are from 0 to 1200 ish with the data I'm using, but I want to normalize that data to show from 0 to 1 with steps of 1/1200. I'm still a novice to Python trying to deal with big data so I apologize if there's a fundamental flaw to my logic here. 

If there is a way to normalize the data (e.g. by doing something like     `plt.hist(agesc, y, bins = 14/.2)`, where y is the data set normalized), then I'd like to do just that.

Comment: did you try passing the `normed=True` parameter? My point is that it shouldn't be surprising that the `plt.hist` function automatically creates a Y axis. Especially if you've done the basic research of reading the documentation, which is usually pretty good for `matplotlib`.

Comment: Didn't get a chance to load it up until now, but `normed = True` almost does it... though it goes from 0 to 1.2 as opposed to 0 to 1. I'm looking over the documentation more thoroughly for sure now.

Comment: Huh? It definitely should not. Your axis may just have a little bit of padding, but the individual bars should sum to 1. You can always change the range of the axis, though.

Comment: [Here's what it looks like](http://i.imgur.com/0PftHhI.png)